# Sketching a surface area and evaluating

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

I just came across this exam question:

Let $$\ S = \{(x; y; z) : z = 3 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} ; x^2 + y^2 \le 9 \}$$
which is the surface of a cone.

(a) Sketch S.

(b) Evaluate $$\ \iint_S 
x^2 + y^2 dS $$

For part B I'm just not sure how to do this.  If anyone can show me how I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: There's a bunch of ways to do this. For instance -  sit in polar coordinates, and recognize that the above integral is the flux of the field $\rho^2 \left(\frac{\hat{\rho} + \hat{z}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ through $S$. Now use Gauss' theorem. An alternate way is to split the surface into two - let $S_1$ be the bottom disk, and $S_2$ be the cone. Calculate the integrals separately over these two surfaces, and add.

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize $S$:
\begin{cases}
x=x\\
y=y\quad \quad \quad \quad\quad \quad\mbox{with}\; x^2+y^2\le 9\\
z=3-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
\end{cases}
Then compute
$$
||r_x\times r_y||=\sqrt{2}
$$
It follows that
$$
\iint_{S}x^2+y^2\;dS=
\iint_{x^2+y^2\le9}(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{2}\;dA=
\int_{0}^3\int_0^{2\pi}r^2\sqrt{2}\;rd\theta dr=\frac{81\pi}{\sqrt{2}}
$$